# Vertical Text Box Carousel with up/down arrows

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, carousel

I'm building a wordpress website, my client sent me the PSD files and converted them to HTML then ready wordpress files. What he's looking for in the about us page is a text box with fixed width and height having scroll buttons look at the image to know exactly how he wants it to look like.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E0QR.jpg

I tried to make it a scrollbar text but didn't work as it should be. I googled for text carousel couldn't find any solution that fits what I need.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to make this situation work.

Comment: Are blocks/chunks/sections of text in question, or whole text (one big block, no separated sections) should be scrolled up/down?

Comment: @nevermind The whole text should manually scroll down if long showing the other part of text. Let say you have a text of 300 words. Box width: 595px and height: 510px where the inner text has  width 398px and height: 431px this shows limitation. So when the text is long the visitor will see the up/down button to scroll down and up. Thanks for your help

Comment: Np, i think this could help you: http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html

Comment: @nevermind thanks for the link I check this one however the problem I don't need the bar in the middle to show up I just need the arrows and I need to customize the arrows replacing them with pictures this can be done through CSS but the scroller should be on the left and the text on right and no bar in the middle just text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be achieved by overflow hidden and manipulating the top value of the test like this example here http://jsfiddle.net/nr0htmrb/1/

HTML

```
<div>
    <p>
        loremLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat quas est sed temporibus nam sint impedit quos voluptatem. Nam sunt voluptate culpa pariatur nisi soluta aspernatur error? Consequatur quibusdam maiores!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam non facere ratione sit neque eligendi quibusdam fugit. Alias unde necessitatibus ipsum nesciunt nulla ad quo reprehenderit quia laborum exercitationem totam.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ducimus illum ullam consectetur error eligendi aperiam molestiae velit sequi iusto possimus libero vel cupiditate quibusdam sit animi ipsum accusamus suscipit.
    </p>
</div>
<span class="up">UP</span>
<span class="down">Down</span>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #e3e3e3;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

p {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
}

span {
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: blue;
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(".up").click(function() {
     var currentTop = parseFloat($("p").css('top').replace('px', ''));
     var newTop = currentTop - 20;
     $("p").animate({top: newTop + "px"});
});

$(".down").click(function() {
     var currentTop = parseFloat($("p").css('top').replace('px', ''));
     var newTop = currentTop + 20;
     $("p").animate({top: newTop + "px"});
});
```

If you want it to work with scroll as well you can also call the same up down function when detecting up down scrolls